# Running C#-project from commandline

Tags: command-line, .net-framework, c#

I'm trying to run an ASP.NET framework from the command line on my local machine using the `dotnet` command. According to the internet, `dotnet restore` requires a project.json file. When I google how to generate such a file, I am told that Microsoft is discontinuing usage of the file in favour of MSBuild and >Projectname<.csproj. I have both these files, but I can't seem to find out how to create the project.json file.

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: What version of .NET is your project targeting?  The `project.json` file and `dotnet` command only apply to the newest .NET Core.  If you're using the full framework you don't need a `project.json` but its also not as easy to run an ASP.NET project from the command line since you need some kind of webserver to serve you web application.

Comment: Its not clear what you mean your trying to run "ASP.NET" from a command line, you need to have a webserver that supports ASP.NET, please edit your question to clarify it.

Comment: @heavyd I'm targetting .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: @Ramhound can't I run ASP.NET locally on IIS then?

Comment: Your title indicates a C# project.  Your question body mentions ASP.NET project.  So which one is it?  Of course you can run ASP.NET locally.

Comment: It's an MVC program written in C# that uses the ASP.NET framework

Comment: Are you wanting to run it under IIS or IIS Express or a different web server?

Comment: For testing purposes I suppose I'll run in on IIS, but whichever works I'll do :)

Comment: IIS runs as a Windows Service, so it is usually always running after it has been installed.